# Copying file selected from jfilechooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm using a filechooser to select an image file. When the open button is clicked i want to copy the image to my project folder.The code isn't showing any errors but nothing happens. nothing is copied.

```
 if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
        File target = new File("/"+file.getName());
        try {
            Files.copy(file.toPath(),target.toPath(),REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(detail1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

}

I used `','` instead of `'+'` in `File target = new File("/"+file.getName());` but no luck, Whats the problem here ?

Comment: Does it log anything?

Comment: Used (System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/images",file.getName());
that solved my problem. is there any problem in using so ?

Comment: @JithinSebastian better make this an answer and accept it, so that this maybe useful for others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my problem:
`File target = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/images",file.getName());`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Java 7 you can use [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) , like this

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "images"), file.toPath());
```